# When changing themes in Wordpress, dealing with different variable requirements?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm managing a wordpress video blog site, and am trying to change our theme to a new one.  Unfortunately, the two different themes store information (like the variable in which the video embed code is stored) [note: I'm using the word "variable" since I don't have a better vocabulary word for it at the moment, but I may be wrong] under different names (so it's not as simple as changing the option in the Theme pulldown menu).

Additionally, while the old theme is fine remotely linking to thumbnails, the new theme demands that they be stored locally.

Needless to say, there has to be an easier way to transition the site than re-copying the embed code and uploading all the images.

However, my programming skills aren't yet up to figuring out the task myself.  (I can generally follow what's going on in code, and can adjust existing code to fit my needs, but can't easily generate it.)  I'm more than willing to dive into the code of the two themes, but am not entirely sure where to begin, or what is safe to change.

(for example, it seems like if I went through the source material for the new theme and changed every instance of their embed variable name to the old one's, that'd work, but then what happens when the theme gets updated?)

I imagine there's an easy way to do it, just one line of code somewhere saying "if the value in variable_new is empty, use variable_old's value, otherwise use variable_new's"   But where?    Or if I went into the database and changed the value in the relevant column to the new variable name...?

Similarly, with the image linking, I'm pretty sure that if I can change the new theme so that what gets shoved into the img tag is a url instead of a local path, that'd solve the thumbnail problem.  But again, where?  And how do I keep from breaking things?

Thank you all.

Comment: Really it will depend on the themes, but the functions.php file is the first place to look. It sounds like the two themes approach things in wildly different ways so I doubt it will be an easy job.

Comment: Thanks, Paul, for your quick reply!  What should I be looking for in functions.php?

Comment: (was supposed to be attached to previous comment)   Both just provide lists of other .php files, including the user functions.php (which is probably where I'll be doing things)

Answer (score 0):

If changing variable names in new theme will do the job you need, you can create a child theme based on it, and place the new variable names there. This article will get you started on [creating and using child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). This way, if the new theme gets updated, your changes won't be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who helped.  The Child theme was an excellent solution, and I'm glad I know about that feature now (and am wondering why I never stumbled across it in my research).

After talking with the team, we decided to just change things in the database, since we won't be going back to the original theme.  Not as elegant a solution as I was hoping for, but making it work is key at this point.